# Need help in coinpayment payment gateway in laravel

Tags: laravel, cryptocurrency, coinpayments-api

I used hexters\coinpayment package of laravel https://github.com/hexters/CoinPayment.
Issue is i didn't received "Transaction Hash" after completing the transaction in callback so how can i?

I trying to Do with IPN with transaction ID but exactly what's the actions i need to do that's not understand.

So how i got the transaction Hash with the use of IPN method In coinpayment??

Answer (score 0):

1. Check CoinPayment Dashboard:

   - Log in to your CoinPayment account.
   - Look for the transaction in the transaction history.
   - Check if the transaction hash is available in the CoinPayment dashboard.
2. Check IPN Logs:

   - If your IPN listener logs the IPN data, check the logs to see what information CoinPayment is sending.
   - Make sure that the `txn_id` parameter is included in the IPN data.
3. Verify IPN URL:

   - Ensure that the IPN URL configured in your CoinPayment account matches the actual URL of your Laravel IPN listener.
   - Double-check for any typos or differences in the URL.
4. Check CoinPayment Configuration:

   - Verify that the CoinPayment package in your Laravel project is configured correctly.
   - Ensure that the `merchant_id` and `ipn_secret` are set accurately in your configuration.
5. Test with a Simple IPN Endpoint:

   - Create a simple PHP script that logs the entire POST data received from CoinPayment. Use this as a standalone script with a URL accessible from the internet.
   - Update the CoinPayment IPN URL to this test script temporarily and make a test transaction. Check if the transaction hash is received in the logs.

   Example test script (`test_ipn.php`):

   ```php
   <?php
   // Log the IPN data for debugging
   file_put_contents('ipn_log.txt', json_encode($_POST) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

   // Respond with a success status to CoinPayment
   echo 'IPN Received and Processed';
   ```
6. Contact CoinPayment Support:

   - If the issue persists, reach out to CoinPayment support. They can help you investigate any potential issues on their end.